# parse rows and conditionally delete a delimiter or token

Tags: excel, vba

my background is in c/c++... I'm still pretty new to VBA, so please forgive me. I'm pulling latitude data into an excel spreadsheet from a database, but I'm getting an unwanted decimal. Below is a fragment I have copied out of the spreadsheet.

Example of invalid data (inserting a decimal after the minutes value that I don't want):

- 38'5.'48.189
- 38'5.'48.023
- 38'5.'48.023
- 38'5.'48.023

Example some valid data:

- 38'10'51.881
- 38'10'51.881
- 38'10'51.881
- 38'10'52.000
- 38'10'52.000
- 38'10'52.000

How can I go through row by row and delete all the .'s that I don't want? Note that I want to keep the actual decimal places of the seconds values. This data is stored in column K of my spreadsheet.

Edit: I know I can convert to a .csv and I know how to write a program in c++ that will do this, but  a vba script would be great for the sake of simplicity. Thanks!

Comment: How are you pulling that data in Excel?

Comment: it comes from a microsoft access database. I didn't write the code for the database, so I'm not sure to be honest. Ideally i would like to go in and fix that on the database end, but that will take much more time for me to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your pick :)

I am assuming that the Data is in Column A

**Using an Excel Formula**

Paste this in Cell B1 and copy it down.

```
=REPLACE(A9,FIND(".'",A9,1),2,"'")
```

**Using VBA**

Replace `Sheet1` with the relevant sheet.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Replace What:=".'", Replacement:="'", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

HTH

Sid

Comment: Thanks! I just had to make a slight modifcation: `=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(".'",K2,1)),REPLACE(K2,FIND(".'",K2,1),2,"'"),K2)` This way it doesn't output invalid excel data if it doesn't find ".'"